# Jenkins pipeline - File Operations Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on Jenkins pipeline (Jenkins version - v2.73.2 ,Jenkins pipeline - 2.5) - using File Operations Plugin where i have a scenario to create a new directory 'Sample' in the workspace c:\workspace and need to copy Test1 and Test2 directories along with sub directories and files from c:\workspace.

```html
Sample
.............
Test1 -> VP1 (only .dll files), VP2 (all sub directories and files), VP3(all sub directories and files), VP4(all sub directories and files)
Test2 -> VP1 (only .dll files), VP2 (all sub directories and files), VP3(all sub directories and files), VP4(all sub directories and files)
```

Below is the syntax i am using which is copying all the .dll files from all the directories which is not expected.

```html
fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '', flattenFiles: false, includes: '**\\*.dll', targetLocation: 'c:\\workspace\\Sample')])
```

Please share your input on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The [includes help page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/file-operations-plugin/blob/9c508d4a2d7f2e9168f2200b2675035f7f9ccf18/src/main/resources/sp/sd/fileoperations/FileCopyOperation/help-includes.html) mentions:

> Files included to copy, this supports ant-style file pattern ex: `target/*/final*.xml`

In your case, you could specify the source folder you expect dll to by copied from:

```
Test1/VP1/**/*.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to copy multiple directories like VP1, VP2 , VP3's sub-directories and files from Test1 directory and VP1, VP2 , VP3's sub-directories and files from Test2 directory .. I am using below syntax which is working. But looking further if there is still any optimize way to achive this.

fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '', flattenFiles: false, includes: 'Test1/VP1/*.dll,Test1/VP2/**,Test1/VP3/**,Test2/VP1/*.dll,Test2/VP2/**,Test2/VP3/**', targetLocation: 'c:\\workspace\\Sample')])

Comment: @Sri Why not `Test*/VP*/**/*.dll`?